# Is it fine to see some illustrations on Google to get an Idea?

Tags: google, inspiration

Sometime I just stuck at a point and my mind doesn't work for the designs. Then I go to google and find the things related to my project. Is it a good approach?

Sometime( knowingly or unknowingly) I also try to follow the design I find on Google.

Is this a good thing to do? I don't know why, but i don't feel comfortable after doing this.

Comment: You may want to search the site for questions related to plagiarism for other facets of this issue. http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=plagiarism

Comment: This has nothing to do with plagiarism, Ahmed is clearly asking about sources of inspiration.

Answer (score 2):

Google is ok to use if you're looking for inspiration - just be aware NOT to copy/plagiarize that art & design.

There are other tools you can get design inspirations from: design magazines (HOW and Communication Arts for example), a folder of your recent logos and designs, design books (check out Creative Workshop), etc. There are also sites for design inspirations and activities you can try. For instance, check this article by Maria Popova about having that mental "creative block" and how you can overcome it:

http://www.brainpickings.org/index.php/2014/02/28/creative-block-krysa

Hopefully this helps!

~L

Answer (score -2):

Drive it like you stole it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CW0DUg63lqU

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8CtC_qbQ51U

TAKE WHAT YOU NEED, THE WAY YOU NEED IT!